# retrieve username and password from web.config

Tags: c#, session

I am working with c#.

I have added username and password to web.config like this.

```
<add key="userName" value="MyName"/>

<add key="userPassword" value="MyPassword"/>
```

Now i want to retrieve these values. Means am using two text boxes to enter username and password.And code to test them is,

```
if(textBox1.text=="some code" and textbox2.text=="some code")
{
response.redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

what should i write in palce of "some code" to retrieve username and password from web.config, so that i can compare them with user entries ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use --> `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyName/MyPassword"]`

However, It is risky to place pwd in a config file, why don't you put it into db table and query it before checking?

Comment: Hey. am just practicing the session states, session expiry etc.

Comment: Do u have any code to put it into db table and query it before checking?